# Calling Nested function

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, nested

I am trying to redraw image after every 10 seconds. by using

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
setInterval("marker()",10000);
});
```

but  marker() function inside initialize() function how can i access only marker to work it for above setInterval

```
 function initialize(x,y) {
  var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(x,y);
  var mapOptions = {
  zoom: 4,
  center: myLatlng,
  mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
 }
 var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), mapOptions);
 marker(x,y);
 function marker(){
   var image = 'myimage.png';
   var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(x, y);
   var beachMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
   position: myLatLng,
   map: map,
   icon: image
   });
 }
}
```

Comment: Do not pass strings to [`setInterval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.setInterval), but the function itself!

Comment: you can call setInterval(marker, 10000);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change it to

```
setInterval(marker, 10000);
```

and move that into a scope where the `marker` function is available, i.e. into `initialize`.